# UTF-8 PHP SQL SERVER

Tags: php, sql-server, wordpress, utf-8

I am working using wordpress, php and sql server. On my web page I have a sqlserver query that is not being displayed correctly.

[problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JZMVc.jpg)

I am not sure of what should I insert on my php or html code to fix this, I have been trying different things but nothing is fixing my problem. I guess it's all about ut8 encoding but I don't know what to do anymore.

This is how I do the query.

```
$dbh = new PDO ("dblib:host=$hostname:$port;dbname=$dbname","$username","$pw");
$stmt=$dbh->prepare("SELECT TOP 10 till.code......
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: Generally, see [Handling Unicode Front To Back In A Web App](http://kunststube.net/frontback/). Specifically, it looks like you're missing `charset=utf8` as part of the connection string (though I'm not sure what charset specifically SQL Server accepts.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
new PDO ("dblib:host=$hostname;dbname=$dbname;charset=utf8","$username","$pw");
```

Answer (score -1):

Probably it's a problem in HTML generated by Wordpress.

Can you check the meta tags in your HTML?

For HTML4:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1">
```

For HTML5:

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
```

You can find further information on charsets here:
http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_charset.asp

Furthermore it is available in PHP a function able to convert in HTML encoded strings some special characters; you could try to pass columns with problems through the **htmlentities** function:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php